# Why Tensorflow-gpu only gives the object prediction once

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I tried the sample code for object_detection. The weird thing was only the first image could be detected. as below:
[image]

I am using
Tensorflow-GPU 2.6
CUDNN 7.6.5
CUDA Version: 11.4
Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 with Max-Q Design

I am totally confused. Could anyone help me on this strange problem?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

import cv2
import time
import numpy as np
import core.utils as utils
import tensorflow as tf
from core.yolov3 import YOLOv3, decode


video_path      = "./docs/road.mp4"
num_classes     = 80
input_size      = 416

input_layer  = tf.keras.layers.Input([input_size, input_size, 3])
feature_maps = YOLOv3(input_layer)

bbox_tensors = []
for i, fm in enumerate(feature_maps):
    bbox_tensor = decode(fm, i)
    bbox_tensors.append(bbox_tensor)

model = tf.keras.Model(input_layer, bbox_tensors)
utils.load_weights(model, "./yolov3.weights")
model.summary()
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

Nonstop = True
num = 0
pngfiles = []
while Nonstop:
    num += 1
    return_value, frame = vid.read()
    if return_value:
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        framename = "./tmp/image_"+str(num)+".png"
        pngfiles.append(framename)
        cv2.imwrite(framename, frame)
    else:
        print("END!")
        Nonstop = False

num = 0
for framename in pngfiles:
    num += 1
    frame = cv2.imread(framename)
    frame_size = frame.shape[:2]
    image_data = utils.image_preporcess(np.copy(frame), [input_size, input_size])
    image_data = image_data[np.newaxis, ...].astype(np.float32)

    prev_time = time.time()
    #pred_bbox = model.predict_on_batch(image_data)
    pred_bbox = model.predict(image_data, verbose=1)
    curr_time = time.time()
    exec_time = curr_time - prev_time

    pred_bbox = [tf.reshape(x, (-1, tf.shape(x)[-1])) for x in pred_bbox]
    pred_bbox = tf.concat(pred_bbox, axis=0)
    bboxes = utils.postprocess_boxes(pred_bbox, frame_size, input_size, 0.3)
    bboxes = utils.nms(bboxes, 0.45, method='nms')
    image = utils.draw_bbox(frame, bboxes)

    result = np.asarray(image)
    info = "time: %.2f ms" %(1000*exec_time)
    cv2.putText(result, text=info, org=(50, 70), fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                fontScale=1, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2)
    cv2.namedWindow("result", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    result = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    cv2.imwrite("./tmp/image_predicted_"+str(num)+".png", result)
    cv2.imshow("result", result)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break
```

Comment: What is the accuracy of your model?

Comment: Thank you for reply. the accuracy is more than 90%. It works well with the same ENV if I am using Tensorflow non-GPU version instead.

Comment: So the problem is with Tensorflow-GPU?

Comment: I am not sure about that. What's kind of problem with tensorflow-GPU it could be? it gave the first snapshot prediction, why it gave nothing for the others. I am totally confused there.

Comment: Did you try to test directly on the video (real-time ) without creating frames ?

Comment: What do you mean by working well without if you use Tensorflow non-GPU version? it draw bbox on the other images?

Comment: Thank you abdou_dev. I tried the real-time video, the same, one first frame can be marked. (in debugging mode).

Comment: yes, if  I use Tensorflow non-GPU version， it draw bbox on the all images.

Comment: What's the output if you execute this code : `gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
    logical_gpus = tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)`

Comment: 2021-10-15 16:13:29.400354: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1510] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5967 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 with Max-Q Design, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
1 Physical GPUS, 1 Logical GPUS

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Hello Abdou, the outputs of the code is as the msg above.
1 Physical GPUS, 1 Logical GPUS

Comment: Maybe you need to retrain again you model using `Tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: Is there any difference between Tensorflow-gpu trained model and Tensorflow-cpu trained model?

Comment: GPU is fit for training deep learning systems in a long run for very large datasets. CPU can train a deep learning model quite slowly. GPU accelerates the training of the model. Hence, GPU is a better choice to train the Deep Learning Model efficiently and effectively.  https://medium.com/@shachishah.ce/do-we-really-need-gpu-for-deep-learning-47042c02efe2#:~:text=GPU%20is%20fit%20for%20training,Learning%20Model%20efficiently%20and%20effectively.

Comment: So, the difference between tensorflow GPU and CPU is efficiency, right? But the problem I  am facing is functional. I don't care how slow or fast it will, I only need all the frames or pictures could be marked.

Comment: But you can just try to retrain using `Tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: Hello @vilonye , Did you solve the problem? I also getting this problem. I don't think it is Tensorflow CPU or GPU problem. Because I use GPU for both training and prediction.