# Tensorflow-gpu only gives the object detection for the first frame

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I have done some code for object detection task. I have done this before a long time ago. But now I want to come back and test the code The model only predict the first frame. This ONLY happen when I use GPU, while CPU is normal

My problem is the same with this question
[Why Tensorflow-gpu only gives the object prediction once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69454617/why-tensorflow-gpu-only-gives-the-object-prediction-once)

Tensorflow 2.8

Python 3.8

Cuda 11.2

GPU RTX2060-m

Answer (score 1):

I have solve the problem. By downgrade cuda to 10.1 and use Tensorflow 2.2 instead